# Vector asset not visible over floating action button

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to put vector asset over floating action button(FAB). Earlier vector asset was visible but after rebuilding the project it is not coming over FAB. please help.

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_diary"
    tools:context=".DiaryActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

VECTOR ASSET

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

PREVIEW:

[image: Preview image]

Comment: It will work, If you have created vector asset. just clear the project and rerun. also check your vector asset present inside drawable.

Comment: clearing and running on device worked but clearing->rebuilding->opening preview did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea on what problem you are facing. May be steps to reproduce might help us knowing your problem